# Lua UI Text == multiple string's with or's

Tags: arrays, string, lua

Now im really new to lua and need a little help with this This script checks some text on the player UI, and It works if It equals one thing for example : `game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Main.Border.ClassLabel.Text == "UNIVERSELORD"`
But does not work if I add the or `game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Main.Border.ClassLabel.Text == "UNIVERSELORD" or "TANKTOP"` It ends up doing it no matter what, and im not sure why, it works if I only put one name though, I would appreciate help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already had the [same question closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70317294/lua-having-an-if-statement-multiple-strings-with-ors) just few days ago due to the lack of details. It's not clear *WHY* you'd want to add "or" to a text, so you need to explain clearly and provide an example with some context where this usage would make some sense.

In terms of the "or" statement, it doesn't produce the result you want because it returns the first result that is evaluated as non-`false`, so when you have `1 or 2` expression, the result is `1`, as it's evaluated left-to-right and this is a non-`false` results. Similarly in your case, the expression `"UNIVERSELORD" or "TANKTOP"` is evaluated to `"UNIVERSELORD"`, as it's the first non-`false` value that is encountered.

Unfortunately nobody can tell you what to change it *to*, as there is not enough details in the question about your goal. Possibly an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

[updated] Based on your comment, you need to split the `or` into two complete comparisons: `game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Main.Border.ClassLabel.Text == "UNIVERSELORD" or game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Main.Border.ClassLabel.Text == "TANKTOP"`

Comment: I understand what your saying but it actually goes through with the if statement while neither of them are true which I dont understand

Comment: There is no `if` statement in your example, so I'm not sure what to tell you. That was the point in my answer that you need to provide more details and some context, as it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: ```
if (game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Main.Border.ClassLabel.Text == "UNIVERSELORD" or "TANKTOP") then
getgenv().Spinloop = false
print("Stopped!")
return 0;
end
```
Heres all code for context

Comment: NullTopdog#9865 is my discord if you want more context

Comment: Updated the answer with a fix for you. You need to be more clear and provide more complete examples.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua, any value that is not `nil` or `false` is considered true.

So in

```
if (game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Main.Border.ClassLabel.Text == "UNIVERSELORD" or "TANKTOP") then
  getgenv().Spinloop = false print("Stopped!") return 0;
end
```

`"TANKTOP"` is a string and hence a true value.

or-ing anything with a true value is always true. So it does not matter if `game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Main.Border.ClassLabel.Text` equals `"UNIVERSELORD"`. The result is always true. Hence your if condition is always met regardless of the text value.